# Mysql replication broken due to 'Duplicate entry' with error code 1062 on slave server

Tags: mysql, master-slave-replication

Mysql Slave replication was working fine, but suddenly it has crashed due to duplicate entries error
The slave SQL thread stops due to duplicate entries in **MySQL DB**, which I have kept in binlog_ignore_db on both Master and slave. 
I have skipped these errors number of times, but keep getting on different tables in MySQL DB(which is default DB). Following are some of the errors, which I got after using `SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER = 1;`

```
Last_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry 'pma_test_host-mysql-pma_test_user' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'INSERT INTO `mysql`.`db`(`host`, `Db`, `User`) VALUES("pma_test_host", "mysql", "pma_test_user")'

Last_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry 'pma_test_host-mysql-pma_test_user-' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'INSERT INTO `mysql`.`tables_priv`(`host`, `Db`, `User`, `Table_name`) VALUES("pma_test_host", "mysql", "pma_test_user", "")'

Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry 'pma_test_host-mysql-pma_test_user' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'INSERT INTO `mysql`.`db`(`host`, `Db`, `User`) VALUES("pma_test_host", "mysql", "pma_test_user")'

Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry 'pma_test_host-mysql-pma_test_user--' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'INSERT INTO `mysql`.`columns_priv`(`host`, `Db`, `User`, `Table_name`, `Column_name`) VALUES("pma_test_host", "mysql", "pma_test_user", "", "")'

Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry 'pma_test_host-mysql-pma_test_user--PROCEDURE' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'INSERT INTO `mysql`.`procs_priv`(`host`, `Db`, `User`, `Routine_name`, `Routine_type`) VALUES("pma_test_host", "mysql", "pma_test_user", "", "PROCEDURE")

Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry 'pma_test_host-mysql-pma_test_user' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'INSERT INTO `mysql`.`db`(`host`, `Db`, `User`) VALUES("pma_test_host", "mysql", "pma_test_user")'

Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry 'pma_test_host-mysql-pma_test_user--' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'INSERT INTO `mysql`.`columns_priv`(`host`, `Db`, `User`, `Table_name`, `Column_name`) VALUES("pma_test_host", "mysql", "pma_test_user", "", "")

Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry 'pma_test_host-mysql-pma_test_user-' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'INSERT INTO `mysql`.`tables_priv`(`host`, `Db`, `User`, `Table_name`) VALUES("pma_test_host", "mysql", "pma_test_user", "")'

Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry 'pma_test_host-mysql-pma_test_user--PROCEDURE' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'INSERT INTO `mysql`.`procs_priv`(`host`, `Db`, `User`, `Routine_name`, `Routine_type`) VALUES("pma_test_host", "mysql", "pma_test_user", "", "PROCEDURE")'

Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry 'pma_test_host-mysql-pma_test_user' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'INSERT INTO `mysql`.`db`(`host`, `Db`, `User`) VALUES("pma_test_host", "mysql", "pma_test_user")'

Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry 'pma_test_host-mysql-pma_test_user--' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'INSERT INTO `mysql`.`columns_priv`(`host`, `Db`, `User`, `Table_name`, `Column_name`) VALUES("pma_test_host", "mysql", "pma_test_user", "", "")

Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry 'pma_test_host-mysql-pma_test_user-' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'INSERT INTO `mysql`.`tables_priv`(`host`, `Db`, `User`, `Table_name`) VALUES("pma_test_host", "mysql", "pma_test_user", "")'

Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry 'pma_test_host-mysql-pma_test_user--PROCEDURE' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'INSERT INTO `mysql`.`procs_priv`(`host`, `Db`, `User`, `Routine_name`, `Routine_type`) VALUES("pma_test_host", "mysql", "pma_test_user", "", "PROCEDURE")
```

My question is why is the slave copying the Database named `MySQL`, while I have explicitly kept it in ignore list and I have also explicitly mentioned the name of DB which I want to replicate.

How should I resolve this issue? I don't want to use `slave-skip-errors = 1062` in MySQL settings as it may lead to inconsistency.

Slave configuration settings shown below:

```
server-id               = 2
binlog_format           = 'MIXED'
log_bin                 = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
relay-log               = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
binlog_do_db            = vi*******n
binlog_ignore_db        = phpmyadmin
binlog_ignore_db        = mysql
read_only               = on
```

Master configuration settings shown below:

```
server-id               = 1
log_bin                 = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog_format           = 'MIXED'
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
binlog_do_db            = ******
binlog_ignore_db        = mysql
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are the master and slaves?

Comment: Slave : `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.53, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3`
Master :`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for Linux (x86_64) `
  It has been working fine for 3 months, so i think version shouldn't matter.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, I wanted to compare versions to see if we were in the same boat. Are you using MyIsam at all?

Comment: @Shaulinator No, I'm not using that.

Comment: @Shaulinator did you find any solution?

Comment: unfortunately no, we have the skip errors set and rebuild the slaves once every few months.

Answer (score 1):

**binlog-ignore-db** is only a master-side setting, it tells the Master not to log changes taking place on the listed DB.

**replicate-ignore-db** is only a slave-side setting, it tells the Slave to ignore incoming log information related to the listed DB

@jugadengg in your case please use **replicate-ignore-db** instead in your Slave configuration.

Comment: I would also like to know why the error is occuring, as the particular DB is put in ignore list on master side.

Comment: @jugadengg i assume that the statement were already in binary log before you apply the ignore on the master and also you were using binlog_ignore_db  instead of replicate-ignore-db on the slave that also can explain why the mysql schema filter was not working. To avoid the crash going forward,  you can temporary use **code** slave-skip-errors             = 1062 **code** and once all the slave is synced to the master remove the slave-skip-errors in your config file to avoid inconsistency

Comment: By gut feelings I did the same and removed skip-erros=1062 when sync was complete.  TIll now for almost a week, no problem has been encountered. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @jugadengg, i'm glad everything is fine, when you have a chance please marked the correct answer then